# Best Practice for Periodic Background Data Retrieval in Flutter: Timer or background_fetch Plugin?

Tags: flutter

I am integrating a feature where a flutter app will connect to the bluetooth watch when the app is in the background state (not killed / user pressed the home button and using another app) to get data periodically after 10 minutes.

To achieve this, I am considering using a plugin called 'background_fetch,' which executes every 15 minutes.

However, I have also noticed that using a timer in Flutter, we can achieve the same functionality. The timer can run periodically even when the app is in the background state (not killed / user pressed the home button and using another app).

So, what is the best practice to use here: the timer or the background_fetch plugin?